# How to solve "Expected a value of type 'int', but got one of type 'String'" in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a local JSON file which looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "1": [
            {
                "mode": "text",
                "value": "text exapple1"
            },
            {
                "mode": "latex",
                "value": "\frac00"
            },
            {
                "mode": "text",
                "value": "text exapple2"
            },
            {
                "mode": "latex",
                "value": "\frac00"
            },
            {
                "mode": "text",
                "value": "text exapple3"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "2": [
            {
                "mode": "text",
                "value": "text exapple4"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

and I am trying to parse it using FutureBuilder in my code:

```
return FutureBuilder(
    future:
        DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString("assets/paragraph.json"),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      var mydata = json.decode(snapshot.data.toString());
      if (mydata != null) {
        return SizeTransition(
            axis: Axis.vertical,
            sizeFactor: animation,
            child: Center(child: Text(mydata["1"][0].toString()))
            );
      } else {
        return SizeTransition(
            axis: Axis.vertical,
            sizeFactor: animation,
            child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
            );
      }
    });
```

Here is the error message I get:

> ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY
> ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
> The following TypeErrorImpl was thrown building
> FutureBuilder(dirty, state:
> _FutureBuilderState#4fb8d):
> Expected a value of type 'int', but got one of type 'String'

and if I do it like:

```
mydata[1][1]
```

it gives me a null output!

What is wrong with this code and how to fix it?

Comment: It's a list containing a Map, so try calling it like `mydata[0]["1"].toString()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your JSON represents at the top level an array because it starts with an `[`. Therefore you have to access the elements with an integer index not with a string. At the 2nd level you have objects which are maps. So I think `mydata[2]["2"]["mode"]` should give you "text". Or what do you expect to output from your JSON using a certain access?

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class ownintegeration extends StatefulWidget {
  const ownintegeration({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ownintegeration> createState() => _ownintegerationState();
}

class _ownintegerationState extends State<ownintegeration> {
  var userdata = [];
  getdatas() async {
    var apidata = await http.get(Uri.https('jsonplaceholder.typicode.com', 'users'));

// var josondata=jsonDecode(apidata.body);
    var getdat = jsonDecode(apidata.body);
    print(getdat.runtimeType);

var user=[];
setState(() {
  userdata=[];
});

    for (var a = 0; a < getdat.length; a++) {
      var obj = {
        "id": getdat[a]['id'],
        "name": getdat[a]['name'],
        "company": getdat[a]['company']['name'],
        "username": getdat[a]['username']
      };
      userdata.add(obj);
    }
   
      print(userdata);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          body: 
      SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(children: [
      
         ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: ScrollPhysics(),
              itemCount: userdata.length,
              itemBuilder: (context,i){
                print(userdata[i]["email"]);
                return Card(
          
                  child: Container(
                    height: 100,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Text(userdata[i]["id"]!.toString()),
                        Text(userdata[i]["name"]!),
                        Text(userdata[i]['company']),
                        Text(userdata[i]['username']),

                        Text(userdata[i]["username"]!),


                // Text("hello")
                
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
                // return Container();
          
          
              }),
         
      
                  ElevatedButton(
                onPressed:(){
                  getdatas();
                } ,
                child: Text("get data")),
          ]),
      ),
     ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than the existing answers. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score -1):

I just solved my return function which gets the data same as this using jsonDecode method which is very important  :

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:http/http.dart';

class NetworkHelper {
  String url;
  NetworkHelper(this.url);

  Future getData() async {
    Response response = await get(Uri.parse(url));
    //print(response.body);
    return **jsonDecode**(response.body);
  }
}
```